# Problem invoking environment variable set up in pom.xml surefire plugin

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, maven-surefire-plugin

I am using the maven-surefire-plugin and I am declaring the environment variable inside my pom.xml. So the issue is that when I declare HADOOP_CLASSPATH my Junit tests can not see it. And it is weird because if I for example declare HADOOP_TEST it works fine. It is not conflicting with system defined environment variable, I opened intellij in the shell where this variable does not exist and it is still not working. Thanks in advance!
[FIrst screen](https://prnt.sc/1u7k2r8), [second screen](https://prnt.sc/1u7jvri)!

Comment: Do not use images https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/296328

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.